# Strange behavior with Conditioned[]

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am using *Mathematica 12.0* on Windows and I recently tried to evaluate a conditional expectation, namely

```
Expectation[Conditioned[X, X < 0.5], Distributed[X, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]
```

However, when running it, I obtain the error message

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of X<1/2.
```

paired with

```
Hold[Expectation[X \[Conditioned] X < 0.5, X \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]
```

I tried closing Mathemtica and re-opening it and it correctly gave me the answer of 0.25. Does anyone know why the behavior of the first try?

I also tried

```
Probability[Conditioned[X, X < 0.5], Distributed[X, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]
```

which remains unevaluated.

---

Adding the method Trace returns

```
Inactive[Integrate][
x*Piecewise[{{0., x < 0}, {2., Inequality[0, LessEqual, x, Less, 0.5]}}, 0], 
{x, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> False, Assumptions -> True]
```

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce this in the Cloud version. Did you try this on a fresh kernel?

Comment: Yes I tried both on a fresh kernel. The first time it gave me the first error, while the second it gave me the correct answer. On both cases the Probability command remains unevaluated.

Comment: Can you try adding the option `Method -> "Trace"` to `Expectation[]` and see what gets returned? (Also, `Probability[]` with `Conditioned[]` expects a relation and not a function, e.g. `Probability[Conditioned[0.2 < X < 0.6, X < 0.5], Distributed[X, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]`.)

Comment: added the output

Comment: If you apply `Activate[]` to that, you presumably don't see any error messages, yes?

Comment: I do not see any error messages

Comment: Perhaps you had defined `X` in the original session.

Comment: `Expectation[Conditioned[X, X < 0.5], Distributed[X, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]` works fine for me on *Mathematica* 12.0.0.0 Windows 10.  @JohnDoty has given you a likely answer.